# Server with high consumption of physical memory; swap is not being used

Tags: linux, memory, swap

Please, I need a help. I have a Linux that has the following scenario of RAM memory consumption:

```
root@cpro15623 [~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3881       3216        665          0         98       1555
-/+ buffers/cache:       1562       2318
Swap:          991          0        991
```

But Swap is not being used and my server is too low!

This is vmstat results:

```
root@cpro15623 [~]# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
302 35      0 1022128 100784 1596548    0    0    23   282  750  877 28 58 14  0  1
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Add output of top would help. Is your php doing any database queries?

Comment: Trust the OS to manage system memory better than you think you can.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal.  The Linux kernel will use free memory to buffer disk access, thereby speeding up your system overall.

[Help!  Linux ate my RAM!](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: But my system is too slow at this moment! A lot of **php** processes under execution. Sometimes my server responds, other times not... What could it be?

Comment: @MarceloJuventino - well, that's an entirely different question. This question is probably going to be closed as a dupe of the other same memory question - feel free to ask another question about your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read this way:

[image]

(stuff to overcome *stupid* 30 chars least limit)